# How to check if XMLReader has valid XML without reading so as to write complete using XMLWriter?

Tags: c#, xml, string, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm trying to write a string(which is nothing but XMLNodes) into a new XML File using XMLWriter. Few of the strings are valid XML content while few of the string aren't.

String Input:
1.

```
<Test>
<A a="Hello"></A>
<B b="Hello"></B>
</Test>
```

2. *Hello
   This is Sample String but not XML*

Code :

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\\Test.XML"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();

   string scontent2 = "Hello This is Sample String but not XML";

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
try{
    using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(scontent))
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
    {
    writer.WriteStartElement("Test");
        writer.WriteNode(xmlReader, true);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    }catch(XMLException exception){}

}
```

**Expected Output:**

The **Test** element must also not be created if the Exception occurs. If I use, `scontent.Read()` or any such, the problem is since the pointer moves to a node, the `writer.WriteNode(scontent,true)` wont write entire nodes(if there are more than two nodes) For ex. `<A a="Hello"></A><B b="Hello"></B>`. In this case, I've write all nodes using WriteNode for which XMLReader must be in Initial State(`XmlReader.State`).

Comment: How about: `try { var element = XElement.Parse("Hello This is Sample String but not XML"); /* at this point the content is xml conform */ element.Save(@"C:\\Test.XML"); } catch  (XmlException ex) { /* at this point the content is NOT xml conform */ }` -- this uses `System.Xml.Linq` (and `System.Xml` for the exception)

Comment: There are many possibilities here. The most obvious is to use `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` and load the original XML all at once, before you start writing the output XML. Alternatively, defer creation of the output file until you've successfully started to read the input. Of course, a file can look like valid XML all the way until the last character and then still fail. What do you want in that scenario? Only reading the entire file before starting to write the output will solve that. Or you can just delete the output after the fact, if the input turns out to be invalid. Too broad.